# Why is Visual Studio 2022 not highlighting my code when an Unhandled Exception is thrown?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, unhandled-exception

When an unhandled exception is thrown in one of my MVC projects, I just get the diagnostic webpage and the debugger does not break at the troublesome line of code.

For example, in my older MVC projects, if I type the line:

```
throw new Exception()
```

then the application pauses and the line is highlighted.  But in my newer .NET 7 project I just get a diagnostic web page but the line of code is not identified which makes debugging ten times harder.

I guess I must have changed a setting somewhere but I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks